# Getting an Alpine JS value inside a blade component?

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade, alpine.js

I have an x-for loop:

```
<template x-for="item in items" :key="item.id">
```

Inside the template I call my blade component:

```
<x-card />
```

How can I pass vars from the Alpine JS loop to the blade component?

I've seen [this](https://gist.github.com/jasonlbeggs/1341e7367c0dc69ac64ef2140d0f0591) and have tried to implement it:

```
<template x-for="item in items" :key="item.id">
    <x-card ::title="item.title" />
    ....
```

But I cannot output the title var inside the blade component.

Answer (score 1):

You can use slots to achieve this. Using this technique you can't directly pass a variable but a HTML element holding your variable.

**Blade file**

```
<template x-for="item in items" :key="item.id">
    <x-card>
        <x-slot name="foo">
            <span x-html="item"></span>
        </x-slot>
    </x-card>
</template>
```

**component file**

```
<div class="card">
    {{ $foo }}
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Right now, it is not possible to pass an alpinejs variable directly to a blade component the way you are trying to do.

You will have to stick with one of those two options:

```
@foreach ( $items in $items )
   <x-card :title="$item->title" />
```

And the inside your component you would likely write something like:

```
<div class="card">
    <h1>{{$title}}</h1>
    ...
```

On the other hand, if you want to do it using alpinejs you could this:

```
<template x-for="item in items" :key="item.id">
    <x-card />
```

And inside the card:

```
<div class="card">
    <h1 x-text="item.title"></h1>
    ...
```

This would work, but of course, it cripples reusability. So, a better option would be

```
<template x-for="item in items" :key="item.id">
        <x-card x-bind:title="item.title" />
```

But, to make it work, your x-card component has to handle the x-bind attribute and initialize the variable within the card scope, like this:

```
<div class="card" {{$attributes}} x-data="{
      title:"",
      init() {
          console.log("init card");
          this.$nextTick( () => {
             this.title = this.$el.attributes.title.value;
          });
      }
}">....
```

Notice the {{$attributes}} tag. Given that you are rendering a blade component, *x-bind* attribute won´t work if the attribute is not present in the rendered blade component. That´s a common pitfall when using alpinejs inside a blade component (or at least it is for me, very often). Also, the $nextTick is needed because your component will run the init method before calculating the bindings, so, if you try to access the title attribute inside the component´s init method, it will be empty.

At this point, this should work. However, I would prefer to do it slightly different:

```
<div class="card" {{$attributes}} x-data="{
          title:"",
          //no attribute initialization here
          init(){
             ....
          }
}">
```

And the declaration like this:

```
 <template x-for="item in items" :key="item.id">
        <x-card x-init="title = item.title" />
```

Some things to clarify using this way: since x-init will be placed inside the component using {{$attributes}} we are changing the title attribute of the alpine component. Another thing to take into account, the init() function inside x-data runs first, and the function inside x-init attribute runs after. So, if you use the title upon initialization to do something, you will have to use this.$nextTick(() => ....) to ensure the value has been initialized.

Now, about why do I prefer to do it this way, it´s because it allows me to keep using it as a regular blade component when needded:

```
@props(["title" => ""]);
<div class="card" {{$attributes}} x-data="{
              title: '{{ $title }}',
              ...
    }"> 
          <h1 x-text="title"></h1>
```

Now, this will work wether I do this:

```
<x-card title="TestTitle" />
```

or this:

```
<x-card x-init="title=item.title" />
```

Sorry if I was too dense, I am relatively new to alpine/livewire, and I still tend to overexplain things due to a lack of knowledge.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

AlpineJS is JavaScript, therefore client side. Blade is server-side. The tip you passed is what is described in the [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/blade#escaping-attribute-rendering) and is just to prevent Blade from evaluating the statement, since Blade can also process single-colon variables.

If your goal is to display the title as text within the card, then have a look at [x-text](https://codewithhugo.com/alpinejs-x-data-x-text/). You should be able to call `x-text="item.title"`. `:title` should be setting the title attribute on the item.

Comment: I'm afraid your response does not answer the question of alpine vars to blade components.

Comment: I don't know if you're using Livewire? If so, it'd be easy. Otherwise, cookies or an ajax request to the server can allow you to set the variable within php and pass it back to blade upon re-render. Like I said, the link you linked does not do what you seem to think it does, and Alpine can't just "give" variables (as __client__ side) to the __server__.